# array search to return index of long string

Tags: php, arrays, search

I want to return index of the array. I am trying the following below but its not working:

```
$os = array("Helo how are you","I am you");

foreach ($os as $oss) {
    if(strpos($oss, 'you') !== false) {
        $reference= array_search('you', $oss);
        echo $reference;    
    }
}
```

I would want the reference to echo  0, 1. given that I am searching for a word 'you' and it occurs in 0, 1. Is array search for a single string? What can do to search in the whole of substring?

Comment: Could you post an example of your array?

Comment: You're using array_search on $oss which isn't an array

Comment: You got your answer below, but maybe instead of fetching the key indexes, it would be better to use [array_filter](http://il1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to reduce your array to a new array holding only the matched elements. That way the keys/indexes won't be important and your code can be clearer. Just a thought.

Comment: That is a task where a database would be great for: `SELECT * FROM os WHERE content LIKE '%you%';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_search()` wouldn't work here as it can't search for partial matches. Instead, you can use the following approach: if the `strpos()` statement evaluates to true, simply display the index for that iteration:

```
foreach ($os as $reference => $oss)
{
    if(strpos($oss, 'you') !== false) {
        echo $reference, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/101705)

Comment: A more functional approach: `echo implode(' ', array_keys(array_filter($os, function($elem) {
    return (strpos($elem, 'you') !== FALSE);
})));` --- `0 1`.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing your foreach loop to this:

```
foreach ($os as $index => $oss)
{ 
  if(strpos($oss, 'you') !== false) {
      $reference= array_search('you', $oss);
      echo $index;    
  }
}
```

Comment: `array_search()` isn't required here (not my downvote, though)

Comment: I didn't know if he needed it for anything else, so I kept it.